# form throwing a internal server error on submit with ajax, django

Tags: django, forms, submit, internal-server-error

I have a form that is throwing a internal server error when i submit it with data

it says it is due to an integrity error:

```
IntegrityError at /cookbook/createrecipe/

(1048, "Column 'original_cookbook_id' cannot be null")
```

what is weird is that i dont have a column original_cookbook_id - what i do have is an original_cookbook that is a foreign key to a cookbook model

here is the view that is giving the error:

```
def createrecipe(request):
        print "entering createrecipeview"
        if request.method == 'POST':
            print "form is a post"
            form = RecipeForm(request.POST)
            print form.errors
            if form.is_valid():
                print "form is valid"
                form = RecipeForm(initial = {'original_cookbook' : request.user.cookbooks.all()[0]})// this is where the error is being thrown
                form.save()

                t = loader.get_template('cookbook/create_form.html')
                c = RequestContext(request, {
                'form': form,
                })

                data = {
                'replace': True,
                'form': t.render(c),
                'success': True,
                }

                json = simplejson.dumps(data)
                return HttpResponse(json, mimetype='text/plain')
            else:
                print "form is invalid"
                form = RecipeForm(request.POST)
                t = loader.get_template('cookbook/create_form.html')
                c = RequestContext(request, {
                    'form':form,
                })

                data ={
                    'form': t.render(c),
                    'success': False,
                }

                json = simplejson.dumps(data)
                return HttpResponse(json, mimetype='text/plain')
```

i think i might be declaring the original_cookbook the wrong way

anyone else have any experience with _id being appended to a foreign key/ have any idea how i might be able to resolve this issue

thanks a lot

katie

**update**

here is my javascript function

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(document).ready(function(){

    function hijack() {
        var form = $('form#createrecipeform');
        form.each (function(){
            this.reset();
            });
        form.submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('ajax form submission function called successfully.');
            //form = $(this);
            console.log(form)
            var serialized_form = form.serialize();
            $.ajax({ type: "POST", 
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                data: serialized_form, 
                success: (function(data) { 
                    console.log('ajax success function called successfully.');
                    data = $.parseJSON(data);
                    if (data.success) {
                        console.log('success');
                        //right now it is logging success to 
                        //console but nothing else is happening
                        //what else should happen on data success?
                    } else {        
                        console.log('failure');
                        var newForm = data.form;
                        form.replaceWith(newForm);
                        hijack();
                    }
                })
            });
            return false;
        });
    };

    hijack();

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have an `original_cookbook_id` field. That's where the pk for the foreign key is store in the table. Django automagically appends the `_id` bit. All the error means is that that field is set to NOT NULL, and you didn't provide a value to `original_cookbook` to fill it in with.

**UPDATE**

There's nothing "wrong" per se, but a few things to note. First, initial only sets the initial value that appears in the form (obviously enough). However, if it's later set back to empty by the user or some other action, it's still empty, i.e. `initial` has no true effect on the eventual posted data.

You didn't post your javascript, so I can't speak to how you're submitting the form, but that too could potentially be an issue. If you're not submitting the field with the rest of the AJAX post, for whatever reason, it doesn't matter what the actual field may or may not be set to.

Comment: ok thank you for clearning that much up
i was under the impression that this line: **form = RecipeForm(initial = {'original_cookbook' : request.user.cookbooks.all()[0]})** was where i was providing a value for original_cookbook. is there something wrong with this method?

Comment: i see what you mean... can you show me an example of what would happen on data.success with a form that is adding an object to a list of objects? thanks for your help chris. i have added my javascript for submit

Comment: i have marked this as correct answer and am going to start a new thread